# How to separate range of year on oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I am working on a db oracle and I need to create a query where it return a range of date. For example:

Supose that I had a field of like this:

[image]

I need to get this dates and apply a range of years to return someting like:

```
|'0-5'|'6-10'|'11-15'|... 
| 10  |  35  |   20  |...
```

where each range contains a number of people in this range of years old.

I tried to use `SELECT CASE...`

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN DATE_BORN <= DATE_BORN + 5 THEN '0 - 5
    WHEN DATE_BORN >= DATE_BORN + 6 AND DATE_BORN <= 10 THEN '6 - 10'
        END AS AGE_RANGE,
    COUNT(*)
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY 1
```

So I saw that this way change only days not year.

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's conditional aggregation:

```
SQL> with test (date_born) as
  2    (select date '2000-05-12' from dual union all
  3     select date '2001-05-12' from dual union all
  4     select date '2012-05-12' from dual union all
  5     select date '2013-05-12' from dual union all
  6     select date '2004-05-12' from dual union all
  7     select date '2008-05-12' from dual union all
  8     select date '2009-05-12' from dual union all
  9     select date '2001-05-12' from dual union all
 10     select date '2012-05-12' from dual union all
 11     select date '2001-05-12' from dual union all
 12     select date '2004-05-12' from dual union all
 13     select date '2005-05-12' from dual
 14    )
 15  select
 16    sum(case when extract (year from date_born) between 2000 and 2005 then 1 else 0 end) as "2000 - 2005",
 17    sum(case when extract (year from date_born) between 2006 and 2010 then 1 else 0 end) as "2006 - 2010",
 18    sum(case when extract (year from date_born) between 2011 and 2015 then 1 else 0 end) as "2011 - 2015"
 19  from test;

2000 - 2005 2006 - 2010 2011 - 2015
----------- ----------- -----------
          7           2           3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, but I need get this values using year + 5 years, because it is impossible to me get all years, because my base have millions of users. So comparete years and year like 2000 and 2005 and others is not possible for me.

Comment: Millions of users? I guess they weren't born in *million of years*. Years may span ... what? 50 years? That's just **10** rows you should code by copy/pasting.

Comment: Yes, but have a lot combinations.

However, maybe I am think wrong, but... 

For example, the question that I need to do for my data is: In the last 12 months, how is the range of years old of my users in range 5 and 5 years and how much people to be in each range?

I'm sorry if my question here not be correct.

Comment: Sample data you posted is rather poor. Years do differ, but all dates are 12th of May which makes confusion. Are days/months relevant? Or just years? Perhaps you should edit the question and post data that illustrate the problem somewhat better, explaining what those values represent and how to get desired result out of that. Because - yes - I found what you said so far (in question and comments) difficult to understand.

Comment: Ok, understood, you are right. I think that only years is relevant. I will use the way that you answer here to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic way to do this (using the sample table above)

First I think it's easier to have your ranges in rows rather than columns, easier for having a variety of dates that may change.

Second your first grouping is 6 years, so I changed it to just be series of 5 years:

```
with test (date_born) as
 (select date '2000-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2001-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2012-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2013-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2004-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2008-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2009-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2001-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2012-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2001-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2004-05-12' from dual union all
  select date '2005-05-12' from dual
  )
  ,mydata AS (
SELECT 
  (SELECT min(extract(YEAR FROM date_born)) FROM test)+((LEVEL-1)*5)dt1 
  ,(SELECT min(extract(YEAR FROM date_born)) FROM test)+((LEVEL-1)*5)+4 dt2
FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL*5 <= 
  (SELECT max(extract(YEAR FROM date_born))-min(extract(YEAR FROM date_born)) FROM test)+5) 
SELECT d.*, count(t.date_born) cnt FROM mydata d 
LEFT JOIN test t ON extract(YEAR FROM date_born) BETWEEN d.dt1 AND d.dt2
GROUP BY dt1, dt2
ORDER BY dt1;
```

You get this for your solution

```
DT1     DT2     CNT
2000    2004    6
2005    2009    3
2010    2014    3
```

Solution is basically extracting years from dates, finding min/max of this data set, using `connect` to get all years in between, and then joining to count your matching records